Way to upload images, using existing Invoke-WebRequest websession, with Powershell 5.1.19041.4522
I have the below code that works to login to a site (not google, just an example), then submit a form on the page, but it requires images be submitted separately to a URL that is created upon form submission.
I have found in PowerShell 6.1.0 and higher there is a form property that will work for my need, but not in my version of Powershell (5.1.19041.4522).
Is there an older way of doing this? I am aware of Invoke-RestMethod option, but if that is the only solution, how can I pass it the websession from Invoke-WebRequest to it, to keep the posting of images in the same session?
$LoginPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.com" -method post -body $PostParams -sessionvariable Cookies

$PostParams = @{blah="yes";etc="yes"}

$Post = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.com" -method post -body $PostParams -websession $Cookies

$FormParams = @{uploaded_file = get-item "c:\temp\yesman.bmp"}

$Image = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.com" -method post -form $FormParams -websession $Cookies

